# Rg Plugins Popup with Xamarin Forms not working for shared project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i am very new to xamarin forms. wanted to show window popup in my project(IOS and Android).
after research i came across Rg.Plugins Popup.

i added nuget package to my project, i am trying to use it but [Demo](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) does not work properly asking for some pakages to installed i do not have any idea which one.

i tried to initialize but `Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();` Init not available....

is there any proper sample code or project to check how to use Rg.Plugins Popup?

Please Help

Comment: did you try package restore in demo example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use popup like page you can use `Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PopUpPage())`. This opens target page like modal dialog.

Comment: no but it does cover whole area..... requirement is to show pages as pop up....i tried to resize the pages with pushmodalAsync but that not happening

Comment: where you have written this Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(); method?

Comment: i am workign on shared project in IOS AppDelegate.cs and in Android MainActivity.cs  different init method depend on platform.

Comment: try to delete bin and obj folder and recompile the application

Answer (score 0):

I suppose You have to add public static class Popup on the shared project, otherwise it will not be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Rg.Plugins.Popup package is dependent only on Xamarin.Forms package 
**>=2.3.0.49.**
 So maybe your Xamarin.Forms package is not compatible with Rg.Plugins.Popup package. Also no need to initialize this package with
**.Init()**
method in 
**MainActivity.cs**
or in
**AppDelegate.cs**
file.

To use Rg.Plugins.Popup package in
**.xaml** file in shared project, you need to include namespace of the package also change the type of page 
**ContentPage**
to namespace_name.PopupPage as shown below:

```
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup">

<!-- Add your design here -->

</pages:PopupPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the version 1.1.4.158-pre on all your projects and it should work.

[[image: Nuget]